# Please stop that troll

Tags: discussion, trolling

A bit much for a flag text, so...

It starts with [New employee has offensive Slack handle due to language barrier](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/78511/new-employee-has-offensive-slack-handle-due-to-language-barrier)
A manager asks what he should do about an employee not able to speak english properly and not able to understand his chat name is offensive and embarassing.

Final update, solved (that was several days ago):

> I asked the other employee who was able to translate to explain which
>   word was the issue, while the employee with the bad handle seemed
>   embarrassed, they were happy to oblige. Definitely was a language
>   barrier issue, but problem solved.

Some days later, the "manager" got suspended in the meantime...

Now, https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/79003/manager-tell-me-slack-name-not-ok appears to be that employee, still not understanding anything in English and still clueless about the meaning of the chat name.

Problems:

- The manager solved the problem some days ago
- The employee has a real name (says it is real) that doesn't exist
- The employee has a Github account created some minutes ago
- The employee somehow knows the exact reason why the manager was banned
- The employee acts too stupid for any human being

=> Can't be legit. And I'm sure that's not the last question from him.

The question gets much activity ... "reward" for such a behaviour...

There is also a second meta post: https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4013/why-i-troll-from-question

Comment: I think it's a little rash to call the first one trolling.  The second question is probably trolling though.

Comment: (Clarification: I mean the second account. The first one is banned anyways)

Comment: Clearly there is one individual with at least two Workplace accounts. I'm still trying to decide if it's two, or three accounts in play. Mods - please nuke at least the obvious two.

Comment: I agree that, while plausible, it's a bit hard to be completely sure.

Comment: An Indian working in NYC definitely doesn't write such poor English, so I am 100% sure it is a troll. Anyway, the account (or at least one of the accounts) is suspended now.

Comment: @MaskedMan The first account was already suspended when I wrote this. That was (probably) the reason for the whole thing, childish "revenge".  ... But I see that the second account got deleted completely :)

Comment: @MaskedMan I've known Indian immigrants since Junior High School.  Not one has ever sounded like this knucklehead.  It sounds more like someone's bad impression of a native American form the 19th century

Comment: The obvious giveway is really that if this person really were the *legitimate* employee, how on earth did they magically *find* stackexchange, the same exact stackexchange site that their manager used, and then also happened to magically find this post, and comprehend enough to know it's about them, and then reply. It could be a very rare coincidence, or it's the same person who obviously knows the site well.

Comment: @stanri Other than that and the things listed above, there's also the fact that this "employee" knew the details why the manager was suspended. I can't imagine a manager proudly telling it everyone.

Comment: @stanri the speech pattern is also very different from an Indian with poor English. It's what someone **trying** to appear to be poor with English would sound like.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Both accounts are deleted now (even the manager), so I guess it's solved.

Answer (score -13):

How I troll? I in America for week, everyone tell me things wrong.  I very frustrated.

Comment: You know, brand new accounts are plausible and everything, I'm not saying you're not real, I kinda find that mean to be honest, but you're bothering people.

Comment: Sorry sorry. I real.

Comment: I not "troll" .